# Add/Remove class from specific div based off screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, responsive

I need to add the class **.full-page** when the screen size is **>= 769px** and remove the same class when screen size is **<=768**. The div I need the class to be applied to has an ID of  *#here* I have tried quite a few things and this is where I left off...

```
<script>

    var windowSize = window.innerWidth;

    if (windowSize >= 769) {
        console.log('Greater than 768');
        document.getElementById('here').addClass = 'full-page';}

    else (windowSize <= 768) {
        console.log('Less than 768');
        document.getElementById('here').removeClass = 'full-page';}

</script>
```

Anyone have a tip? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd better [use media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) here

Comment: P.S. The console logs are showing at the appropriate screen sizes in Dev tools, the script just isnt working.

Comment: If you still want to use this instead of media queries, then look for [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className). Your `addClass = ...` makes no sense.

Comment: I can't target the class through media queries very cleanly since it is part of a theme and there is several classes working in tandem there. But to get it to work the way I need just turning that class off will work for now. Also its passing through an Advanced Custom Fields repeater field so i'm avoiding breakage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`window#matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to detect width changes, and see if it matches a certain criteria. Use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add and remove classes.

You can see an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u6c8akt4/). Change the width of the bottom right rectangle by dragging the border.

---

**Code:**

```
var classList = document.getElementById('here').classList;

var minWidth769 = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 769px)");

function match() {
    minWidth769.matches ? classList.add('full-page') : classList.remove('full-page');
}

minWidth769.addListener(match);

match();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks a lot, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

There is no method **add|remove Class** in JavaScript, if you want to change class for an element, you can use

```
document.getElementById('here').className = 'full-page'
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('here').setAttribute('class', 'full-page')
```

Comment: in fact there's classList, it just doesn't work on old IE

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use jQuery if you want to use 'addClass', after link the jQuery file,
Try

```
$("#here").addClass("full-page");
```

and

```
$("#here").removeClass ("full-page");
```